# How to insert boilerplate everytime a key is invoked in vim?

Tags: vim

When I'm coding in C/C++, when I type '{' I generally want the next couple characters to be a newline, tab, newline, ended by '}'. This is especially convenient with top-down programming so that you can make the format of your function and continue on, only to come back later and it has already been prototyped for you.

So, to clarify, I want '{' to be replaced by

`{\n\t\n}`

Is that possible in vim, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

is this ok for you?

```
inoremap { {<cr>}<esc>O<tab>
```

with this mapping, if you type `foo`<kbd>{</kbd> in INSERT mode, it will change to:

```
foo {
    I
}
```

- `I` is cursor position.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested to try out some of the many "auto closing" plugins available. I use [DelimitMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754) but you could try [AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2009) or [AutoPair](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599).

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of yank registers. Perhaps the simplest solution would be to yank that to a designated register and then put from that register each time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

For that kind of "top down" coding with "auto prototyping", snippet plugins are excellent.

With a snippet plugin you can do much more extensive "top down" coding than just expanding brackets.

[Ultisnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715) is a great snippet plugin. If you don't have python support in your vim, then [SnipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), the predecessor of Ultisnips, is quite capable also, but not as advanced.

With Ultisnips, you could use any of the three snippets below:

**1)** Create the brackets and place cursor following them

```
snippet {
{

}
$1
endsnippet
```

**2)** Create the brackets and place the cursor within them

```
snippet {
{
    $1
}
endsnippet
```

**3)** Create the brackets and place the cursor within them, then <kbd>Ctrl-j</kbd> to place the cursor following the brackets

```
snippet {
{
    $1
}
$2
endsnippet
```

*But* in addition to simple snippets like these three, you could get much more sophisticated, defining whole function/class/etc templates in snippets that can be quickly expanded and jumped through.